# Show sgn($\sigma$) = $(-1)^{k-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\sigma \in S_n $ be a cyclic permutation of length $k$. Hence:

$\qquad (a_1, \dots, a_k) :\quad a_1\mapsto a_2\mapsto a_3\mapsto \dots\mapsto a_k \mapsto a_1  $

for all $a_i \in $ {$1,\dots,n$} pairwise distinct.

How can I show that  sgn($\sigma$) = $(-1)^{k-1}$?

Comment: What is you definition of the signature?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question?

Comment: No. There are different ways to define the signature of a permutation and it will probably affect the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
(a_{1}, \dots , a_{k})
=
(a_{1}, a_{2}) (a_{1}, a_{3}) \dots (a_{1}, a_{k}),
$$
where I am composing permutations left-to-right.